# xelatex to epub3 with pandoc and footnote links?

Tags: footnotes, pandoc, epub

I am creating an ePub like this:

> pandoc test.tex --latex-engine=xelatex  -o e.epub  --bibliography=works-cited.bib  -f latex -t epub3+footnotes

However, instead of getting footnotes like this in the ebook reader:

> This is some text<sup>1</sup>

I am getting this:

> This is some text.(Author 2004, 40)

Having spent an hour on the pandoc site, I can't find an option to change this, what am I missing?

**UPDATE:**
It appears something like `autocite=footnote` may impact the output, but I have not worked out a way to get this to work at this point. I am currently trying:

> \usepackage[style=sbl,backend=biber,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

Comment: You might need to specify a CSL style that supports footnotes, cf. http://citationstyles.org/styles/

Comment: This has nothing to do with xelatex. Also: please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a file `test.tex` like this:

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=sbl,backend=biber,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{works-cited.bib}

\begin{document}
This is some text.\autocite{Author2004}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And a bibliography called `works-cited.bib`:

```
@BOOK{Author2004,
    AUTHOR = {Author},
    YEAR = {2004},
    TITLE = {Title},
}
```

Then you will get a pdf like that:

[image]

---

To convert this input to `.epub` with `pandoc` you need a csl file that [supports notes](https://www.zotero.org/styles?format=note) like [`chicago-note-bibliography.csl`](https://www.zotero.org/styles/chicago-note-bibliography?source=1).

Since `pandoc` uses no latex engine to convert to epub it ignores all latex options, but you have to specify the csl file you've downloaded earlier with the option `--csl` instead.

Running`pandoc` with the following options will suffice:

```
pandoc test.tex --bibliography=works-cited.bib --csl=chicago-note-bibliography.csl -t epub3+footnotes -o e.epub
```

Result:

[image]